# task decorator is not called with script task

Tags: azure-devops, decorator, azure-pipelines-yaml

Creating a task decorator. But it does not work.

**What I did**

I run this pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: 'echo Hello, world!'
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

I build this decorator.
vss-extension file:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "decoratorId",
    "version": "1.0.12",
    "Name": "My decorator",
    "publisher": "Amethyste-MyTasks",
    "public": false,
    "categories": [
        "Azure Pipelines"
    ],  
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "my-required-task",
            "type": "ms.azure-pipelines.pipeline-decorator",
            "targets": [
                "ms.azure-pipelines-agent-job.post-job-tasks"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "template": "my-decorator.yml"
            }
        }
    ],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "my-decorator.yml",
            "addressable": true,
            "contentType": "text/plain"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I set the m--decorator.yml like:

```
steps:
- script: echo 'Decorator-injected Task'
  displayName: 'Run my script (from decorator)'
```

The decorator is not invoked.

But if I use:

```
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Decorator-injected Task'
  inputs:
    script: echo This is from the Decorator for Build
```

It works fine.

**What I tested**

I checked the tabulation is OK (Yaml).

**My questions**

Why the first test is not working?

Comment: They are different, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 'script' ≠ 'CmdLine Task', script is just a shortcut, I think you know what is the different between 'shortcut' and 'the object actually responsible for the execution'.

'script' equivalent to passing an inline script to the CmdLine task. Parser does this under the covers - transforms script into task: CmdLine. They are not the same, their relationship is like the 'shortcut' icon you see on the desktop of the Windows system and the '.exe executable file' in the root directory of the software installation.

Basically 'script' is the same as 'aaa', 'bbb' or 'xxx' from the perspective of the parser, their presence will not only cause failed to recognize them, but also will directly destroy the entire decorator and cause the decorator not to be loaded. .

So please use the original Task: [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)